# Artifactory's Conan repository is Not Found

Tags: artifactory, conan

I am trying to setup **Artifactory OSS** repository with **Conan**. Everything seems to work fine in Artifactory console. In instructions of "Set me up" in Artifacory OSS it says:

> To add the repository to your conan CLI, use:
>
> > `conan remote add <REMOTE> http://192.168.0.1:8081/artifactory/api/conan/random-project`
>
> And replace  with a name that identifies the repository (for
>   example: "my-conan-repo")
>
> To login use the conan user command:
>
> > `conan user -p <PASSWORD> -r <REMOTE> <USERNAME>`

In **Conan** I've followed the instruction:

```bash
$ conan remote add some-random-project http://192.168.0.1:8081/artifactory/api/conan/random-project
> WARN: Remotes registry file missing, creating default one in /home/homie/.conan/registry.txt
```

And when I try to add user:

```bash
$ conan user -p admin -r some-random-project admin
> ERROR: b'{\n  "errors" : [ {\n    "status" : 404,\n    "message" : "Not Found"\n     } ]\n}'

  Invalid server response, check remote URL and try again. [Remote: some-random-project]
```

Also, when I trying to access `http://192.168.0.1:8081/artifactory/api/conan/random-project` with `GET` request, it gives:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 404,
            "message": "Not Found"
        }
    ]
}
```

Before I was using **Artifactory Pro** and I was following the same procedure, and it worked.

**Could you tell me what the problem is?**

Comment: The Artifactory that supports conan is not OSS, but "Community Edition" =CE, could you please make sure (maybe edit the question with details to it), the URL you used to download the Artifactory you are using?

Comment: I have installed OSS. Where could I find CE version?

Comment: Because I have search for Community Edition, bet every time it links to Open Source edition.

Comment: You can find all of the version and types of installations in this link:
https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Artifactory-Cpp-CE/view

Comment: You solved my problem! Maybe could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not downloading the correct version of Artifactory:

- Artifactory OSS: It has support for Java and generic repositories
- Artifactory Community Edition (CE) for C/C++: It has support for Conan packages and generic repositories.

Make sure to download the Artifactory CE to use it with Conan, follow this link: https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Artifactory-Cpp-CE/view. The links from the conan.io downloads page should work too: https://www.conan.io/downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want a nice and short way to start artifactory CE with docker-compose:

1. checkout the official repo from artifactory: https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples.git
2. navigate to docker-compose/artifactory
3. edit the artifactory-oss.yml to point to the ce docker image, e.g.: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-cpp-ce:6.13.1

The available tags are listed here: https://bintray.com/jfrog/reg2/jfrog%3Aartifactory-cpp-ce

...never the less, be sure to set your conan remote to the correct URI, which in case you run the Artifactory CE locally will look something like this: `http://localhost/artifactory/api/conan/<repository_name>`

Comment: For me I did not have the correct URL and this answer gives it to use.  If there is any other place this is documented it would be good to know.

Comment: Found the documentation here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/use-conan-with-artifactory